# Why is Cloud Zoom not functioning properly on new variation type?

Tags: commerce

I am using Commerce Kickstart and trying to add a new variation type to my webshop.

However, it seems that it won't work. This displays an extra block that I can't seem to hide and the controlls are 'jumpy'.

The cloud zoom settings are as followed (and exacly the same as in the functioning example).

```
Slide image style : product_full
Zoom area image style : full_original_size
Gallery settings
Gallery mode : 1
Thumbnails image style : product_thumbnail
Zoom area possition
Zoom width : auto
Zoom height : auto
Position : inside
Adjust X : 0
Adjust Y : 0
Zoom style
Tint : false
Tint opacity : 0.5
Lens opacity : 0.5
Soft focus : 0
Smooth move : 3
Show title : 1
Title opacity : 0.5
```

Functioning example: http://suppsbv.com/webshop/nl/productdisplay/lipo-100-60-caps

Not functioning: http://suppsbv.com/webshop/en/smaak/extreme-whey-deluxe-pouch

I can't seem to find the answer, so any help would be appreciated.